# Buying a domain SEO friendly or the brand name?

Tags: seo, google, domains, google-search, search-engines

I have the company name SOME COMPANY and my main keyword some keyword. What is more clever to do, to buy

```
somecompany.com
```

or

```
some-keyword.com
```

What is the best approach?

In the old days i would use some-keyword.com but now days i heard that the CONTENT is more important and the domain doesn't count that much, what do you guys think?

Thank you for every answer.